# scan email body for encryption with PHP

Tags: php, email, encryption

I'm in the process of making an anonymous email relay but as a further step to protect both parties I would like to make sure that encryption is used in communications.

How can I parse the body of the email to make sure that no "cleartext" is sent in the email.
I will the return the email along with an article(or link to one) describing how to encrypt emails.

I think I'll have to parse the body for common words (the, a, can, how, why, where, when, etc) or the "header" of the PGP key block or the key attachment.

EDIT
still in "brainstorming stage" i wanted to know if it was possible or not

Comment: "Hi I was just reading your unencrypted email when I noticed that your email is not encrypted..." I'm sure it will go well.

Comment: @Sammitch it's just a question of wording: "It seems your email is not encrypted. Don't worry we have not saved or used the contents of your email, but other parties might not care about your privacy as much as we do and, for this reason, we won't relay your email. Go to [LINK to some tutorial] to learn how you can secure your email communications."

Comment: @Eli Algranti, that's about what i was thinking.
maybe mirroring a Tute and some PGP distros too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the headers/markers for common encryption methods:

[S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) should have a valid MIME header identifying the message as such.

PGP [does not have a MIME type yet](http://www.imc.org/smime-pgpmime.html), but it uses [text markers](http://www.thebook.com/pgpfaq.html) which you can look for:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: 2.6.3a

[ENCRYPTED MESSAGE HERE]
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Other encryption schemes should have similar facilities for identifying them.

Searching for common words is not a good idea as it presupposes:

1. The message is long enough to use the common words.
2. The message is in English.

Comment: "but it uses text markers which you can look for:"
this is probably the way i'll have to go. the only problem is if something other than PGP is used.

Comment: A cursory research seems to indicate PGP and S/MIME are the most widely used encryption systems. You should be fine if you support both.